# Scala - Use different equality comparisons/hashing for the same type

Tags: java, scala, hashcode, equality

So, in .NET, you can define implementations of `IEqualityComparer` and pass them to the constructor of a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`. Otherwise, the collections will look at the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

This is extremely useful when you have multiple ways of comparing objects. For instance, you could look up a `Person` by primary key, domain name, email address, etc.

Is there an idiom in Java and Scala for achieving the same thing? I would think there was something easier than creating multiple sub-classes to simply override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302593/how-to-provide-custom-hashing-and-equiv-implementations-for-immutable-hash-sets

Comment: Have a look at the `Equal` type class in Scalaz.

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) Java library provides an [`Equivalence`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class to implement custom equivalence relations.  It doesn't support altering the equivalence semantics of the `Set` or `Map` directly, but it can be used to wrap the elements so that they can be compared using the custom equivalence relation.

```java
Person person1 = Person.withEmail("john.doe@example.com");
Person person2 = Person.withEmail("jane.doe@example.com");
Person person3 = Person.withEmail("john.doe@example.com");

Equivalence<Person> emailEquivalence = Equivalence.equals().onResultOf(Person::getEmail);

Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<Person>> set =
        Set.of(emailEquivalence.wrap(person1), emailEquivalence.wrap(person2));
assert set.contains(emailEquivalence.wrap(person3));

Map<Equivalence.Wrapper<Person>, Integer> map =
        Map.of(emailEquivalence.wrap(person1), 1, emailEquivalence.wrap(person2), 2);
assert map.get(emailEquivalence.wrap(person3)) == 1;
```